# What is maximum number of concurrent ssh session can we create?

Tags: linux, ssh

I understood the maxconcurrent session depends on MaxSessions attribute and somaxconn

Please help me on this following questions:

1. what is the MaxSessions maximum value
2. why somaxconn value is very important in here. what is the maximum value we can give
3. what exactly the maximum concurrent ssh sessions in number
4. i got to know eacch of my ssh session assigned with a new port number internally as shown in picture . What exactly new port numbers

[image: netstat]

Comment: The maximum value will depend on how much your hardware can support.  What sort of testing have you done?

Comment: just for curiosity , what will be the maximum if we have enough hardware to unlimited session

Comment: There is always some limit. Just the RAM for example. So you are limited by RAM, swapfile or disk. Mostly you will have first problem with number of processes that service the SSH.

Answer (score 1):

> I understood the maxconcurrent session depends on MaxSessions attribute and somaxconn

Nope. Maximum of concurrent session depends on how much is your hardware able to handle. The `MaxSessions` is used for limiting amount of sessions per single connection. It is usually limited by the maximum of opened files:

```
$ ulimit -a
[...]
open files                      (-n) 1024
```

> 1. what is the MaxSessions maximum value

The value is [stored in `int` data type](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/servconf.h#L150), which is at least 16 bits by definition, but on nowadays architecture, it is possible to carry up to 2 147 483 647 (which is obviously bigger than the maximum of opened files).

> 4. I got to know each of my ssh session assigned with a new port number internally as shown in picture . What exactly new port numbers

The port numbers are the ports on the remote hosts and they are assigned randomly, if this is the question. And what you see are not the sessions, but the connection (which from each can operate more sessions using `ControlMaster`).